# Angular JS get value into another variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `$scope.user = {}` when I do this `<input type="text" ng-model="user.name">`the name in the input gets stored into `$scope.user` how do I get that value into another variable?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('WizardController', ['$scope', function($scope){

      $scope.user = {};
      $scope.displayName = $scope.user{'name'};

    }]);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant:

```
$scope.displayName = $scope.user.name
```

or

```
$scope.displayName = $scope.user['name']
```

Also, if you want to display the value of '$scope.user.name' somewhere in your html (which is what I assume you're trying to do) you can do something like this:

```
<h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want it to automatically refresh $scope.displayName in your view when you update $scope.user.name you'll need to add this to your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('user.name', function () {
    $scope.displayName = $scope.user.name;
});
```

However, there's probably very few good reasons to do it that way.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3752/ (Updated from one in comment to include logging).

Comment: Actually that won't work as by the time that line of code `$scope.displayName = $scope.user.name` is executed the `user` property on the `$scope` has no name value, and changes to `user.name` will not be propagated to `displayName`.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure that if you were to log $scope.displayName at some point after changing $scope.user.name that it would represent the correct value but I agree that's probably not what is intended. I updated with a watcher (though I think this is probably usually a sign that something needs refactoring). Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3750/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put it in another variable you just have to make a new one.

$scope.newName = $scope.user.name;

The content will be put into the newName scope. Is that what you mean?

$scope.displayName = $scope.user{'name'}; I think you want to rewrite it to:
$scope.displayName = $scope.user.name or $scope.user['name'];